# How to increase kernel overheat threshold?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, temperature

I have spontaneous logouts, probably caused by overheating. I have the following lines in `syslog`:

```
Jul 23 13:44:19 studebaker kernel: [  491.025664] CPU8: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jul 23 13:44:19 studebaker kernel: [  491.025665] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Jul 23 13:44:19 studebaker kernel: [  491.025666] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
```

How to see / change that threshold, mentioned in error message?

Comment: I thought that was a non-writable hardware setting

Comment: Then how to see it? An/or how to change reaction for it?

Comment: How about figuring out what causes overheating and make it not do that, alternatively checking fans and cooling? I would have thought overheating would be a symptom rather than a problem to fix in itself.

Comment: What's your motherboard and CPU? Please do `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Mo"` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know what causes overheating -- normal work. For example, compiling or syntax checking in `CLion`. I can't avoid it sorry, I got computer not for decoration.

Comment: @Dims Normal work should never cause overheating. You may have cooling issues.

Comment: @K7AAY overheating itself is discuseed here, you can participate: https://superuser.com/questions/1437589/dell-xps-15-logout-on-overheat

Comment: @Kusalananda should not but still causes :)

Comment: _Dims_, have provided an experience-based answer to your Superuser question. Is that the laptop you refer to in this question? If so, which model of XPS 15 do you have (Dell has many different XPS 15s)? Please see my request in my comment above.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to *see* the thresholds under `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.?/hwmon/hwmon?`. The values replacing the question marks will depend on your system; the first is likely to be 0.

You’ll see a number of files named `temp?_crit`, `temp?_crit_alarm`, `temp?_input`, `temp?_label`, and `temp?_max`. The values replacing the question marks vary again, starting at 1, and increasing to cover temperatures for the package and all the (real) cores in your system. `_label` tells you what the set of values describes, `_input` shows the current temperature, `_max` the maximum temperature, `_crit` the critical temperature, and `_crit_alarm` indicates whether the critical temperature alarm has triggered.

You can’t *change* these using kernel-provided interfaces, they’re set by the CPU and/or system firmware. You shouldn’t try to change them anyway, they’re designed to protect the CPU from damage. If you’re bothered by the overheating messages you should try fixing the overheating problems instead — the ambient temperature might be too high, the CPU’s cooling could be hampered by dust, etc.

The messages in your kernel’s logs don’t reflect the kernel’s decisions; they’re the translation of machine events that the kernel is being told about. Your computer noticed that its CPU was getting too hot, so it throttled it, on its own, and told the kernel about it.

Comment: Each of these files contain `100000`, are these millidegrees? :)

I understand your common recomendations, but they are not applicable.